# Can we apply filter on measures in where condition?

Tags: ssas, mdx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7GMk.png)

```
select {[Measures].Allmembers} on columns,[Dim Customer].Allmembers on Rows from [Rightdata Db] where [Measures].[Quantity].&[43]
```

when i execute the above query, I get the exception below:

> Query (1, 97) The '&[43]' member was not found in the cube when the
>   string, [Measures].[Quantity].&[43], was parsed.

Why am i not able to apply filter on measures using where condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont filter Measure in this way. Take a look at the sample below

```
select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity]} on columns, 
{
filter([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>10000)
}
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: it helped me! Cant we filter measure with where condition? @MoazRub

Comment: You can put the filter in Where but it will not work as it worked above. If the answer helps you solve your problem, you might consider marking it as answer.